# Removing spaces only in certain zone

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like this:

> this is my text          more text texttext and here comes something special [S p e c i a l string] more random text

What I would like to do is to remove the spaces *outside* the brackets, so the final result would be:

> thisismytextmoretexttexttextandherecomessomethingspecial[S p e c i a l string]morerandomtext

Right now I'm removing the spaces just doing

```
myString.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
```

But, is there a way of selecting only the desired part?

Comment: Any personal thoughts?

Comment: Yes, but it implies cutting the whole string in multiples (there could be several "special strings" and then removing spaces separately. I was wondering if there is a better way

Comment: So start with something that *works*. Then if you find it doesn't fit the performance, code quality or some other requirements - return here with your solution. You must realize there is no "a better way" for literally "nothing". Because everything is better than nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var myText = @"this is my text more text texttext and here comes something special [S p e c i a l string] more random text";
var pattern = @"\s+(?![^\[]*\])";
var output = new Regex(pattern).Replace(myText, "");
```

output will hold:

```
thisismytextmoretexttexttextandherecomessomethingspecial[S p e c i a l string]morerandomtext
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
var result = string.Join("\"",
               test.Split('\"')
                   .Select((s, i) => i%2 == 1 ? s : s.Replace(" ", string.Empty)));
```

It splits the string by double quotes, and selects every alternate split item for the replacement operation - then joins them up again.

Comment: Note - this doesn't work if the delimiter characters are different on either side of the quoted block. So with the OP's edit to use square brackets instead of quotes, this code no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like

```
stringbuilder sb = new stringbuilder();
bool should_remove = true;

foreach (var c in my_string) {
    if (c == your_start_special_char)
        should_remove = false;
    else if (c == your_end_special_char)
        should_remove = true;   
    else if (c != ' ')
       sb.append(c);
}
```

mind the upper cases and syntax ... not on VS atm ...

Another option would be to splice it depending on your special areas and remove spaces from the regular ones ...